# How Spring injection works for subclass

Tags: spring

A question on how Spring injection works? If I inject same service in a class and all its sub-classes is it going to to inefficient? How does Spring's container going to store/control this?

```
public class baseClass {
    @Autowired
    private iService serviceName
}

public class extendedClassA extends baseClass {
    @Autowired
    private iService serviceName
}

public class extendedClassB extends extendedClassA {
    @Autowired
    private iService serviceName
}
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried but I believe it is going to cause problem.

The main problem is not due to Spring, but variable shadowing in your example.  BaseClass' `serviceName` is shadowed by child class, that means, if you haven't done special handling, BaseClass' `serviceName` is going to be null.

You may want to consider doing this:

```
// !!!! Mind your naming convention!!!!!!
public class BaseClass {
    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    protected FooService getFooService() {
        return this.fooService;
    }

    public setFooService(FooService fooService) { ... }
}

public class ExtendedClassA extends BaseClass {
    // no need to inject fooService again, whenever it need to use that,
    // simply do getFooService() and use it
}
```

Comment: I was able to run my code, just fine, i wrote an abridged version of my class. My question was about "If I inject same service in a class and all its sub-classes is it going to to inefficient?"

Comment: Well, if Spring has properly handled the shadowing issue (as you suggested), there is nothing "inefficient" then.  It just looks awful as u are unnecessarily injecting multiple times.  And, if in any case you need to change the value of that field in your code, it is going to be error-prone, because of shadowing issue.  e.g. `void someMethod() { this.fooService = this.someSpecificFooService; }`

Comment: Is there any problem in simply declaring `fooService` as protected?

Comment: no special problem I can think of.  That's the use of `protected` anyway.  Of course, it is always the best to expose least internal to other class, even child class

Answer (score 0):

Adrian Shum response seems fine but you need to declare too your BaseClass bean in your applicationContext file with the property "abstract=true"

```
<bean id="baseClass" class="BaseClass" abstract="true"/>
```

Comment: I was able to run my code, just fine, i wrote an abridged version of my class. My question was about "If I inject same service in a class and all its sub-classes is it going to to inefficient?"

Comment: Abstract Bean has nothing to do with class inheritence hierarchy